# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `xs` supplied to `ForwardRef(Grid)` - Error in Material UI Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
    <React.Fragment>
  <CssBaseline />
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container direction='column'>
        <Grid item container>
            <Header/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item container>
          <Grid item xs={0} sm={2}/>
          <Grid item container xs={12} sm={8}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/bouquets">
                <Bouquets />
              </Route>
              <Route path='/about'>
                <About />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={0} sm={2}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ThemeProvider>
</React.Fragment>
```

I get the error in the title in the console when running my react app. This is Material UI Grid component, and I don't really understand the error or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing properties in the GRID component.

Following the mui documentation:
https://mui.com/components/grid/#grid-with-multiple-breakpoints

```
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
          <Item>xs=6 md=8</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={4}>
          <Item>xs=6 md=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={4}>
          <Item>xs=6 md=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
          <Item>xs=6 md=8</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

As you can see you have first the Grid with property container. Then inside you can use as many Grid with property item as you want.

But inside of Grid with property item you should have only items(Componets like Typography, Button, Avatar or whatever component you have) and not more Grids.

So your code should be something like:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <CssBaseline />
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container direction='column'>
        <Grid item >
            <Header/>
        </Grid>
       </Grid>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/bouquets">
                <Bouquets />
              </Route>
              <Route path='/about'>
                <About />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Grid>
         <Grid/>
    </ThemeProvider>
</React.Fragment>
```

I hope I have clarified how to use the container or item property in the  component and that it helps you to solve your warning.

Comment: Thank you so much! your comment helped me figure it out and use Grid the proper way. I had followed a guide that used that empty Grid spacer instead of justifyContent, the correct way. no more red console errors!

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you have a CONDITIONAL SX returning NULL:

sx={null} = TYPESCRIPT WILL BARK AT YOU!

---

```
<Box sx={ condition1 && {...sx}} > </Box>
```

so when condition1 is FALSE, it returns NULL... and SX, can NOT have NULL as its value...

so do this:

```
const mySx = condition1 ? {...sx} : { }

 <Box sx={ mySx } > </Box>
```

so now its either: SX values OR empty object, and Typescript will stop barking at you  =)